# In Python, if auth_user_id is not None, fails to match None?

Tags: python, nonetype

How do I stop my code from executing when a variable is None? I have tried many things. Here is my current incarnation:

```
post_body = request.POST
auth_user_id = post_body.get("auth_user_id", None)

if auth_user_id is not None:
    print(auth_user_id)
    search_user = SearchUser.objects.get(user_id=auth_user_id)
```

Right now this code dies on the last line with this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'None'
```

And this:

```
        print(auth_user_id)
```

Shows me "None".

So what is going on? How do I stop the code on None?

Comment: Probably `None` is string. What is output of `print(type(auth_user_id))`? Is it `<class 'NoneType'>`?

Comment: @sKwa no need to ask, it IS a string obviously else the OP would get a `TypeError` not a `ValueError`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously what you get here is the literal string `'None'`, not the `None` object - note how the error messages differ, when passing `None` you get a `TypeError`, when passing `'None'` you get a ValueError:

```
# py2.7

>>> int(None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
>>> int('None')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'None'


# py3
>>> int(None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
>>> int('None')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'None'
```

Your problem comes from the HTTP request body (since it's a POST) containing the literal string `'None'` for the "auth_user_id" key. Note that using a Django Form with proper validation would avoid the problem.